# Error in deployment of Next JS 14 typescript inside cPanel server

Tags: typescript, deployment, cpanel, next.js13

/home/hitmugir/nodevenv/appFront/16/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:28 class NextRequest extends Request {
^

```
ReferenceError: Request is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hitmugir/nodevenv/appFront/16/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:28:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
    at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at Module.mod.require (/home/hitmugir/nodevenv/appFront/16/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:65:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hitmugir/nodevenv/appFront/16/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/next-request.js:37:18)
```

Environment variables:
`USER=root PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin PWD=/ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 TZ=Asia/Tehran SHLVL=1 HOME=/root RESTARTSRV=1 _=/usr/sbin/httpd PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=true SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.4.58 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.1.1w mod_bwlimited/1.4 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.18`
User and group:
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

PID
2211722
Backtrace

`in bool Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::checkCurrentState() (Perform.h:238)
in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::waitUntilSpawningFinished(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)' (Perform.h:213)
in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::execute()' (Perform.h:1752)
in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::internalSpawn(const AppPoolOptions&, Passenger::SpawningKit::Config&, Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakeSession&, const Passenger::Json::Value&, Passenger::SpawningKit::JourneyStep&)' (DirectSpawner.h:211)
in 'virtual Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::spawn(const AppPoolOptions&)' (DirectSpawner.h:261)
in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (SpawningAndRestarting.cpp:95)

I tried different versions of
In next.config, I put output in export mode and put the contents of the folder in public html, it was decorated as SPA.
`